# Aggregation subquery , search inside list of a specific _id

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Ater many lectures i canot say if its possible to perform this sql equivalent query in **1 query** with mongo : 
 `SELECT * from collection WHERE _id NOT IN (SELECT blacklist from collection WHERE _id = 1 )`
I tried many thing with aggregatio but didn't manage to work.

Here is my collection :

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "blacklist" : [8,9,10,3]
    "code_postal" : 67110,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            7.72, 
            48.91
        ]
    }
}

{
    "_id" : 2,
 "blacklist" : [18,1,93]
    "code_postal" : 67110,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            7.63, 
            48.91
        ]
    }
}

{
    "_id" : 3,
     "blacklist" : [7,3]
    "code_postal" : 67110,
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            7.7, 
            48.96
        ]
    }
}
```

**Result expected with this query and this collection should be** (_id 3 excluded because is in the blacklist of _id 1):

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "blacklist" : [8,9,10,3]
        "code_postal" : 67110,
        "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                7.72, 
                48.91
            ]
        }
    }

    {
            "_id" : 2,
         "blacklist" : [18,1,93]
            "code_postal" : 67110,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ 
                    7.63, 
                    48.91
                ]
            }
        }
```

regards

Comment: Why would you think that SQL translates to anything here? It's not even valid SQL. What do you think the result should be? Just trying to work out what it is you are asking here.

Comment: i know this sql is not valid, but the logic is understable no ? thats kind of semi join or subquery if you prefer..

Comment: No it's not understandable. Which is I why I asked you to at least edit the question to show what result you would expect if you cannot otherwise explain that much more clearly.

Comment: i edited the question, is it more clear ?!

Comment: Nope. Because all I see here is a useless use of a subquery to just arrive at the value `1`, which can then just be excluded from the `_id` value as you are asking. You might as well just do that as the sub-query serves no purpose.

Comment: please see my edit , question is understable i think and the result idea makes sens..

Answer (score 4):

I think you should save yourself the trouble and just use two queries (first, get the blacklist, then query documents) but if there's really no other way:

```
db.so.aggregate([
{
    // First, choose what fields to return (less is better)
    // and only return a certain document {_id: 1}'s blacklist.
    $project: {
        _id:         1,
        code_postal: 1,
        loc:         1,
        bl:          {
            // Only return blacklists if the parent has 
            // a certain ID.
            $cond: {
                if:   {$eq: ["$_id", 1]}, // or a different value
                then: "$blacklist",
                else: 0
            }
        }
    }
},

{
    // Group all documents in one, so that we can embed the
    // blacklist into all documents, not just in {_id:1}.
    $group: {
        _id:       null, // Group everything.
        items:     { $push: "$$ROOT" },
        blacklist: { $max: "$bl" } // "{}" is higher than "0".
                                   // This makes sure that we only
                                   // get one blacklist, not
                                   // [ [], 0, 0, 0, ... ]
    }
},

{
    // Pull the documents apart again.
    $unwind: "$items"
},

{
    $project: {
        _id:         "$items._id",
        code_postal: "$items.code_postal",
        loc:         "$items.loc",
        whitelisted: {
            // If everything in the following array is true,
            // then the _id is not in the blacklist.
            $allElementsTrue: [{
                $map: {
                    // Iterate over $blacklist
                    input: "$blacklist",
                    as:    "currentId",
                    in:    {
                        // If the ids don't match, return true.
                        $ne: ["$$currentId", "$items._id"]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
},

{
    // Only find non-blacklisted documents.
    $match: {
        "whitelisted": true
    }
}

]);
```

Note that because this groups all documents into one, you'll have to take care not to exceed [Mongo's document size limits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-operator-and-memory).

This produces the following:

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "code_postal" : 67110,
        "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                7.72, 
                48.91
            ]
        },
        "whitelisted" : true
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "code_postal" : 67110,
        "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                7.63, 
                48.91
            ]
        },
        "whitelisted" : true
    }
]
```

Comment: Wow , so that seems possible but very complex.. I need to study ur answer but perhaps i should add some details fot "what i want to do that in 1 query ? " .Because the list of id in the blacklist field can be pretty huge, i mean +1500 item and the second query post size will big, not sure but i think its not a good idea to have in my second query a NOT IN (list of 1500 id) ?!

Comment: Well, you're trying to do something like a join in a DB without joins.  
Compare the performance of the solution above vs running two queries (with a small & large id list). I'm guessing that sending a list of 1500 ids might be faster than the solution above. [Profile it using $explain.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/)

Comment: I would go so far as to say **will be faster** and the cost of even small lists from another query negates the additional cost of all the processing of the example pipeline. Adding whole collections in a single document is just not practical if not usually impossible. But I think you made a decent effort to explain the example to @user4406273 so it stands well for that.

Comment: This is just one of those cases where correctly answering the question isn't, well, *the* answer.